# How do I prove that $ex/\ln(x)$ is the function traced out by the successive functions?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics, transcendental-numbers

Why is the purple function equal to $ex/\ln(x)?$ How do I prove this?

After tracing out successive blue functions I wanted to find the function that passed through the minimum points of the successive blue curves. After a while I found it. But I'm not sure why the constant factor is equal to $e$. Can someone shed light on this?

[image]

Comment: @Seth - Please be careful before editing. Using $e^x$ instead of $ex$ substantially changes the question.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. I thought it was just a typo on the OP's part. I'll be more careful in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let

$$f\left(x\right) = \cfrac{x}{\ln x} \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
$$g\left(x\right) = \cfrac{N - x}{\ln\left(N - x\right)} \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$
$$h\left(x\right) = f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right) \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

You want to know why the limiting behavior of $h\left(x\right)$ is $e f\left(x\right)$. To see this, check where the derivative of $g\left(x\right)$ is $0$. Using the product & chain rules, we get that

\begin{align}
g'\left(x\right) & = -\cfrac{1}{\ln\left(N - x\right)} + \cfrac{\left(N - x\right)\left(-1\right)\left(-1\right)}{\ln^2 \left(N - x\right)\left(N - x\right)} \\
& = -\cfrac{\ln\left(N - x\right)}{\ln^2\left(N - x\right)} + \cfrac{1}{\ln^2\left(N - x\right)} \\
& = \cfrac{1 - \ln\left(N - x\right)}{\ln^2 \left(N - x\right)} \tag{4}\label{eq4}
\end{align}

Assuming $\ln\left(N - x\right) \neq 0$, this gives that

$$\ln\left(N - x\right) = 1 \Rightarrow N - x = e \tag{5}\label{eq5}$$

Plugging this into \eqref{eq2} gives

$$g\left(e\right) = \cfrac{e}{\ln\left(e\right)} = e \tag{6}\label{eq6}$$

You could differentiate \eqref{eq4} again to show the $2$nd derivative is positive at $x = e$. Alternatively, since $\ln\left(N - x\right)$ goes to $0$ as $N - x$ goes to $1^+$, this indicates that $g\left(x\right)$ goes to $\infty$. Similarly, as $N - x$ goes to $\infty$, $g\left(x\right)$ also goes to $\infty$. This shows that \eqref{eq6} is a local minimum. As such, the equation

$$m\left(x\right) = \cfrac{ex}{\ln x} \tag{7}\label{eq7}$$

provides a lower bound for those sections of the various functions in \eqref{eq3}.

Answer (score 1):

For a given value of $x$, the choice of $N$ that hits the boundary there is the one whose function is minimal, as a function of $N$.  So do ${\partial f(x,N)\over \partial N}=0$ and solve for $N$ as a function of $x$.